# ssh is disconnected when gem5 is compiled

Tags: ssh, vscode-remote, gem5

When I build gem5 on vscode over ssh with the host, every time I get halfway through the build, I disconnect and I can't connect to the host anymore.

vscode displayed that failed to set up dynamic port forwarding connection over ssh to the vs code server
Is it a port problem？

Comment: With the little info provided, it's impossible to tell. Just a suggestion, I would look at memory consumption. Exhausting mem could cause swapping and/or killed processes and thus affect the SSH connection as well.